# Insert Arabic words into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, ascii

I would like to insert/read Arabic words into mysql database

When I insert Arabic words from Chrome, I see them in DB ASCII
When I insert from FireFox, I see them in DB Unicode
See this picture from my DB: http://postimg.org/image/6ht95v671/

I need everything to be inserted in ASCII only

Note: I insert only from php form using POST method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Solving programming problems requires,well,code.

Comment: I found the problem from the browser Encoding not from utf8 lol

Answer (score 1):

For each new table you create, during creation, set its default character set to UTF8 and you should be good to go:

Here are the full [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

And here is some example sql

```
CREATE TABLE my_great_table('some_column' VARCHAR(1024)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Arabic characters can't be written in ASCII. It's an 8 bit character set that quite literally does not have the room to insert anymore characters into it besides 0-9, a-z, A-Z, punctuation, and some invisible command characters.

Here's a chart on [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

Comment: I found the problem from the browser Encoding not from utf8 lol

Answer (score 0):

You could always convert it to hex before putting it in the database

```
function strToHex($string){
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}
```

and then get the values by converting the hex to string

```
function hexToStr($hex){
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
```